# Training Gaussian Restricted Boltzmann Machines with Noisy Rectified (nrelu or ssu) linear hidden units

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, training, gaussian, rbm

I'm not sure how to implement this architecture. I'm following [this thesis](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Endjaitly/Jaitly_Navdeep_201411_PhD_thesis.pdf) (pages 17-19) or [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Efritz/absps/jaitly_ICASSP2011.pdf) but I'm not sure how to train it. I want to use this to extract features from raw audio.

I know I have to compute the positive and negative correlations, but I don't know how to do this exactly since I can not find any detailed documentation of this.

What I have done so far is:

## Positive correlation

To compute it I do a matrix multiplication:
$$\langle xh\rangle^+ = \frac{x_{data}^Th_{act}}{batchsize}$$

Where $x^T_{data}$ is be my batch data transposed and $h_{act}$ are the hidden units activations. $h_{act} = relu(x_{data}W + bias_{hidden})$. Not sure if I have to add noise in this point.

## Negative Correlation

To do this I use contrastive divergence (no tag??) with $k=1$

Same thing:
$$\langle xh\rangle^- = \frac{x_{free}^Th_{free_{act}}}{batchsize}$$

but I'm really not sure how I have to compute these terms.
So for me $x^t_{free}$ would be the **samples** of $\mathcal{N}(ΣWh+b;Σ)$, where $h$
here is activation from previous step ($h_{act}$) without noise.
Lastly $h_{free_{act}}$ is computed as the same as the previous $h_{act}$ but using $x^t_{free}$

Is this correct? Because I don't know when I have to use samples or activations or maybe meanfields